# How to remove decimal places from a series of long string

Tags: sql-server

I have a requirement of removing all decimal places from a geometry coordinate( which is in the form of a string). The string cab very long with (X1 Y1,X2 Y2..) style string. For example

> LINESTRING (16663853.61163 -3899663.2262,16663622.467
>   -3899330.1621,16663432.9106 -3899211.7555)
>
> Expected results:   LINESTRING (16663853 -3899663,16663622
>   -3899330,16663432 -3899211)

Please help.

Comment: That's just a string, not a geometry. It does look like a WKT representation of a geometry, but as far as SQL is concerned, it's just a string. SQL, the language, is terrible at string manipulation. On the other hand, SQL Server has spatial types. You can convert the string into an actual [geometry](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/spatial-geometry/spatial-types-geometry-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) type eg with `geometry::STGeomFromText('LINESTRING (100 100, 20 180, 180 180)'`  and manipulate the points in the string

Comment: If you don't want to work with geometry/geography (you should if you are working with polygons), I'd suggest using a string split function to split by space, then converting the values to INT or removing the decimals with a substring + charindex.